# what is the meaning of projection of spin along z axis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, hilbert-space, quantum-spin

Spin is an internal degree of freedom, which has no classical analogue. So what is the meaning of its projection along z-axis? if it is the internal degree of freedom and **its Hilbert space is a 2-dimensional Hilbert space(for spin half)**, so why we are bothered about its projection in z-axis in real space?

Comment: you are right about the internal degree of freedom but for real-world particles, it acts like an angular momentum and the behaviour changes in external fields as the measurement is being done in real space.

Comment: If you want to be precise, this projection is simply expected value of particular quantum operator. Even if spin itself is described via spinors which lives in 2 dimensional representation space, it doesn't exclude its measurable in 3d, or even has 3 dimensional representations